# this MSXML 6.0 package is not supported on the current processor type winetricks ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, winetricks

so i just run winetricks for ubuntu 18.04 with this run

```
sh winetricks msxml6 gdiplus gecko vcrun2005 ie6
```

and it's said

```
This MSXML 6.0 package is not supported on the current processor type
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: Please run `uname -i` and post output here.

Comment: x86_64 sir thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to install 32-bit `msxml` on 64-bit system, which is why it throws an error, you could try download it directly from Microsoft server.

Try:

```
wget -P /tmp https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/a/f/eafb8ee7-667d-4e30-bb39-4694b5b3006f/msxml6_x64.msi
WINEPREFIX="${HOME}/.wine" wine64 msiexec /i /tmp/msxml6_x64.msi
```

`WINEPREFIX` point to your current wineprefix, you can changes it to the one you had— though the default location should be at `/home/user/.wine`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the very same problem and by accident found a very easy fix:

1. In PlayOnLinux, go to *Configure* → *Wine* → *Configure Wine* → *Libraries*.
2. Then in *New override for libraries* look for *msxml6* and add it.

That did the job for me.